# Kotlin Singleton Class vs Normal Class

Tags: android, kotlin, singleton

I am new in kotlin and i read lots of documentation about singleton pattern and kotlin object declaration. I have some problems about singletons.

- Firstly, If singletons are beneficial for device memmory, Why is it used so little?
- How can we decide, we need to use singleton or not ?
- Why we need multiple instances exactly if singleton beneficial for memmory?
- If we don't need constructor can we use `object` all the times instead of `class` ?

And lastly i have a class which is authenticating phone number by using firebaes api

```
class PhoneNumberAuth {

private val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
private lateinit var callbacks: PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
private lateinit var storedVerificationId: String
private lateinit var resendToken: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken

fun SendVerificationCode(
    activity: MainActivity,
    phoneNumber: String
){
    callbacks = object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        override fun onVerificationCompleted(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {

            Log.d(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted:$credential")
            auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
        }

        override fun onVerificationFailed(e: FirebaseException) {

            Log.w(TAG, "onVerificationFailed", e)

            if (e is FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {

            } else if (e is FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {

            }


        }

        override fun onCodeSent(
            verificationId: String,
            token: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken
        ) {
            storedVerificationId = verificationId
            resendToken = token



        }
    }

    auth.setLanguageCode("en")
    val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(auth)
        .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
        .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .setActivity(activity)
        .setCallbacks(callbacks)
        .build()
    PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)



}
```

Should I use it like `class PhoneNumberAuth{}` or `object PhoneNumberAuth` How can i make a decision like these situations, how to understand which one is useful than other ?

Comment: What exactly are you confused about? If you need multiple instances, it has to be a class. If your design works with a single globally accessible instance, an object can work. However, using too many global objects with mutable state makes your code hard to test and hard to debug.

Comment: You use a singleton if you need only one instance.  You use a class if you might need more than one.  There's almost never a choice about when to use a class and when to use a singleton, just like you don't usually have to choose between a hammer and a saw.  You use them for different things.

Comment: Actually I dont know when I need multiple instances or single instance in a real project. That's why I confused. Could you give some examples ?